# Time steps in RNN and LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, recurrent-neural-network

I am quite new to recurrent neural networks and how to use them for sequence classification.

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how RNNs (specifically LSTMs) capture time. That is, can LSTMs be used for classification on multivariate trajectories evolving in continuous time?

For example, a Markov Chain approach is not an explicit modelling of time and thus one needs to consider some additional feature for this.

So for RNNs, does time also have to be captured via features somehow?

Comment: RNNs can accomodate continuous time if, for example, you pass a predictor for "time between observations".  This can work sufficiently well depending on the problem, but if you're interested in modelling in continuous time (because you have irregularly spaced samples of some continuous process) neural ODEs may be better.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at neural ODEs. I did have another thought, could one also use Continuous Time Bayesian Networks to deal with this?